# Is it possible to EXPLAIN ANALYZE COPY from a file to a table in POSTGRESQL?

Tags: postgresql, sql-execution-plan, postgresql-14

I'm trying to analyze if the triggers before and after on my table with huge data to check for any bottlenecks and for improvements but i'm getting syntax error and wanted to see if it's possible to do EXPLAIN ANALYZE COPY

i did some research but couldn't find if it's possible or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) the following statements can be explained

> Any SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, VALUES, EXECUTE, DECLARE, CREATE TABLE AS, or CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW AS statement, whose execution plan you wish to see.

The `COPY` command is not in that list